# How to count integers

Tags: r, count, numbers

I have a CSV file with the ages of people (500 people),

```
ages <- csv.read("ages")
```

but it has errors like `0.83` or `25.50`. 
How can integer numbers be counted?

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're asking but you can round to the nearest integer using `round(ages)`. Or to test which age values are integers, you could call `ages == round(ages)` which will return TRUE if there is no decimal part.

Comment: What is `csv.read`? What are you talking about when saying that instructions "has errors"? What even numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean you want to know which numbers are integers. If so, try the following

```
numbers = c(0.1, 1, 2.8, 3)
integers = numbers[numbers == floor(numbers)]
numbers
# [1] 0.1 1.0 2.8 3.0
integers
# [1] 1 3
```

It works by rounding down each number to the nearest integer and then comparing with the original. If these are the same then result must be an integer.